# reactive forms radio button default value checked

Tags: html, angular, radio-button

I'd like the radio button to have a default value as `checked`.
I have tried the following without any success.

```js
  form: FormGroup;
  gifts: IGift;
  this.form = this.fb.group({
            phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0][5][0-9]{8}$')]],
            email: ['', [CustomValidators.email]],
            k_gift: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.gt(0)]],
        });

        this._giftService.getUserGifts()
            .subscribe(g => {
                this.gifts = g;
            },
            error => {
                if (error.includes("401")) {
                    localStorage.removeItem("token");
                    location.reload();
            })
```

```html
 <input type="radio" [value]="gifts.k_gift" aria-checked="false" attr.id="gift{{gift.k_gift}}" formControlName="k_gift" >
                                    <label class='control-label' attr.for="gift{{gift.k_gift}}">
                                        {{gift.desc_k_gift}}
                                    </label>
```

The value inserted to gifts.k_gift is `1`. I have tried  `[value] = 1` , and tried also `k_gift: [1, [Validators.required, CustomValidators.gt(0)]],`
Also tried `checked` in the html `input` tag.

None worked for me.
How can I set the default of this radio button as `checked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a model-driven form. Instead of using the `[value]` input in the template, set the model accordingly:

```
this._giftService.getUserGifts()
    .subscribe(g => {
// here
        this.gifts = g;
        this.form.patchValue({ k_gift: /* insert desired value */ });
    },
```